# Can't install node-sass package via npm

Tags: node.js, npm, google-chrome-os, npm-install, node-sass

I recently used [Chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew) to install Node v4.4.0 on my Chromebook.

The `node` install went through great, and all of my packages installed with the exception of `gulp-sass`, which is dependent on `node-sass`.

This is the error I get after running `npm install node-sass`

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/chronos/user/druid/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.18
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/chronos/user/druid/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/chronos/user/druid/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.18
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-sass"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/chronos/user/druid/npm-debug.log
```

Any ideas why I am running into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that doesn't seem to contain the actual log.  all it says is `Error: make failed with exit code: 2`.  but if it's running `make`, it most likely is trying to compile code, and that requires a C/C++ compiler, and that isn't available under Chrome OS currently.  you'd need to install a distro into a chroot like [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

Comment: Though I've used crouton before, I went ahead and removed chromebrew. Couldn't solve the issue, so I just used crouton.